# Dynamically add items to grid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls, itemsource

I have the following 'Grid`:

```
<Grid x:Name="ImagesGrid" Grid.Row="1"  >
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FrameViewers}" />
</Grid>
```

I also have the following collection of `UserControl` items:

```
private ObservableCollection<FrameViewer> m_frameViewers = new ObservableCollection<FrameViewer>();

public ObservableCollection<FrameViewer> FrameViewers
{
    get => m_frameViewers;
    set
    {
        m_frameViewers = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

I would like to dynamically add `FrameViewer` to my screen, to make it look like the attached image: [image]

Currently I'm seeing them sorted vertically like this: [image]

I was able to play with the 'Grid' and added a `StackPanel` to the `ItemSource`, but then they were all sized by the length of the title, and attached to the left side of the `Grid`

What am I missing here?
What am I missing?

Comment: First of all, you can set the orientation of your ItemsSource StackPanel to list them horizontally instead of vertically.

Comment: I did that, but then they did not take the entire size of the `StackPanel` - they were all aligned to the left..

Comment: You may use a UniformGrid, with a specified number of rows or columns, as your ItemsSource.ItemsPanel. It will give your items an equal width and fill the available space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ItemsControl by default will arrange the items vertically.

For a horizontal layout, you need to change its `ItemsPanel`, to a different `ItemsPanelTemplate` - using either a horizontal StackPanel, or something like a UniformGrid, depending on what you want to happen when there are more than three FrameViewer items in the collection.

See [here](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/) for some examples.

You would then need to set the ItemsControl `ItemTemplate` to an appropriate `DataTemplate`, to ensure that each FrameViewer item is displayed at the required size.

Comment: Thanks! And for those who are seeking an answer, here's what I did:                         <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FrameViewers}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                 <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                         <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
                  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>